# Ratings with count average and users post

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, average

I know how to get the count and avg in one SQL

SELECT COUNT(col) AS cnt, AVG(col) AS avg FROM tbl;

But how would you also get the result which a user has posted? Can this all be done in one?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
select user, count(col), avg(col) group by user
```

With your info:

```
SELECT domains_ratings_domain
       , COUNT( * ) 
       , AVG( domains_ratings_rating ) 
       , (select domains_ratings_rating FROM domains_ratings T2 WHERE T2.user=T1.user)
FROM domains_ratings  T1
GROUP BY domains_ratings_domain
```

Comment: `code` SELECT domains_ratings_domain, COUNT( * ) , AVG( domains_ratings_rating ) 
FROM domains_ratings
GROUP BY domains_ratings_domain `code`

thats the code I have, which gets the domain, count, avg and now I want say the rating the user=1 has put in as well?

Comment: How is the user rating stored. Is there a column in the same table with userid?

Comment: domains_ratings_id,domains_ratings_domain,domains_ratings_user,domains_ratings_date,domains_ratings_rating - is my table

Comment: One more question. If on same page I wanted to show a table with say every rating; date, rating, user will this need to be done in a separate query x

Comment: yes it does. But thats not a bad thing. Its just that grouping rows and showing all rows dont go together